# Protege: Create new class out of an attribute

Tags: protege

So, I would like to do what the title suggests without manually rewriting everything. Here's what I want in Protege terms:

Given a file where there are:

- A Class MyClass
- Some Instances I of MyClass
- Some values V_i such as for every I: I hasMyAttribute V_i

I am looking for a way to create this new file:

- A Class MyClass
- A Class MyAttributeClass
- V_i Subclasses of MyAttributeClass where V_i are the values of hasMyAttribute
- Now, I is an instance of Subclass V_i if in the original file I hasMyAttribute V_i

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no other answer available I will describe my way around the problem.
I did a bit of manual work:

1. I add MyAttributeClass
2. I add one by one the V_i subclasses
3. On the description tab, I define "Equivalent to:" hasMyAttribute value V_i
4. Start the Reasoner(Hermit in my case)
5. File -> Export Inferred Axioms

Hope that will be helpful.